# HTTP Handler and 404 error for a custom file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, httphandler

There is something that is not so clear to me with regards to Custom HTTP Handler.

I have created a `ScriptTranslator` HTTP Handler according to [this blog post](http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx)
I have registered the handler in my web.config file in the following way:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
        <add name="ScriptTranslatorHandler" path="*.js.axd" verb="*" type="CamelotShiftManagement.HttpHandlers.ScriptTranslator" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also added an `IgnoreRoute` command to my global.asax so the web-app could fire up the handler according to the we.config file.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.js.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

The handler is suppose to translate a JS file reference from my html file, so I modify my script reference and add an `axd` extension at the end.

The handler receives a request and searches for the file without the axd extention to get the script content that is need to be translated, here is the basic `ProccessRequest` action :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string relativePath = context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Replace(".axd", string.Empty);
    string absolutePath = context.Server.MapPath(relativePath);
    string script = ReadFile(absolutePath);

    string translated = TranslateScript(script,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    context.Response.Write(translated);
    Compress(context);
    SetHeadersAndCache(absolutePath, context);
}
```

So in my html file I modify only the reference of the script tag, there is not actual file called `myscript.js.axd` there is a file called `myscript.js`.

I get a 404 error.

I am frailly new to creating and using a custom Http Handler and I don't know what to expect from the usage.

The referenced [blog post](http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx) implies that there should be not actual .js.axd file in the code and the request for the script reference will reroute to the handler and process the actual .js file by using the first 2 lines in the code I provided before that.

I wounder weather or not setting a custom HTTP handler should run the handler code first and only then throw a 404 error,or should I create a dummy myScript.js.axd file to support the handlers action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore url must look like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{resource}.js.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Then add:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.js.axd" verb="*" type="..." />
    </httpHandlers>
    ...
  </system.web>
```

and:

```
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers>
        <add name="ScriptTranslatorHandler" path="*.js.axd" verb="*" type="..." />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Also check namespace, file `ScriptTranslator.cs` doesn't contain it

**Added:**

Default `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` ignore only `localhost/test.axd`, not 'localhost/Home/test.axd`, then application try to find matched route and it can't find it, then we receive 404.

Comment: Did exactly as you wrote .. the only thing I needed to change was the value passed to `IgnoreRoute`.. you have added "Scripts/" before {resource} but that still did not work. What do you mean about the namespace of `ScriptTranslator.cs`.. currently it's `CamelotShiftManagement.HttpHandlers`

Comment: okay! I found it myself .. the script itself located in a sub-folder of /Scripts... so i changed the value to /Scripts/Administration/ and presto.. it works.. now one more question .. how can I make an Ignore rule for all sub folders under Scripts?

Comment: @Mortalus Try something like: `routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{folder}/{resource}.js.axd/{*pathInfo}");`

Comment: It worked perfectly! thank you! So the reason i got the 404 is that the MVC routing engine took over and my js.axd did not get rerouted by the http handler ? could you include that in your answer so i could mark it as completed ?

Comment: @Mortalus `IgnoreRoute` and `MapRoute` didn't match url, then application throw 404, if url match `IgnoreRoute`, then aplication didn't check `MapRoute` rules and `HttpHandler` executes.